# CD $Variable not working when used in a (Bash) Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

File name: Test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ZDir="$(echo /usr/src)"
cd "$ZDir"
```

When I execute the script `./Test.sh`, the command `cd` doesn't do anything. 
If I try to do it directly in the bash terminal, it works like a charm.
Also, echo, used inside and outside the script, returns me the correct value (`/usr/src`).

Does anyone know why this happens?
Again: `cd $ZDir` works if used outside the script, directly in the terminal...

Edit: Could'nt find the answer on the "duplicate" one but that G-Man user right there answered exactly what i needed to do.
Just included a && followed by the next command i needed to do and worked.
Functions can also be used for this...
cdZDir() {
    cd /usr/src;
    make;
    make install;
}

Then just call in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd` only affects the *current* shell and its descendants. 
Shell scripts are run in new shell processes,
so a `cd` in a script affects only
the remainder of the execution of the script, and any programs it runs.

- If you put commands like `pwd` and `ls` *into the script,* after the `cd`,
  you’ll see that the `cd` has succeeded *in the script.*
- If you say `. ./Test.sh`,
  your current (main) shell process will read `Test.sh`
  and execute the commands therein. 
  Then you’ll see that your current (main) shell process
  will be in the new directory.

Comment: Well, i need to do a make install inside a directory and i can't do it if cd does'nt go to that directory.

Comment: Like cd /usr/src && make && make install

Comment: I asked a new question because the one listed as 'already answered' did'nt helped me. I don't get it. I don't know how to source the script ". ./script"

Comment: (1) It seems that what you want to do is to put the entire `cd /usr/src && make && make install` command line into the script.  (2) What’s there to know? You type a dot (**`.`**). You type a space (`⁠ ⁠`). You type the name of the script (with or without the `./`). And you press “Enter”.

Comment: Hey G-Man. Thank you! Based on what u just said, i did using && on the same line and worked like a charm!

Comment: Since the commands i need to do are pretty large, i made a function called cdZDir that does cd /usr/src; make; make install; and also workeeed. Thank you so much, appreciate it. Couldn't find the answer on that "duplicate" one

Comment: You’re welcome.  Since my answer helped you, please “accept” it by clicking on the checkmark (below the voting buttons).

Comment: oh Sorry, i forgot. Just did it, thanks again!